# Map .csv file to openproject database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, openproject

I have a .csv file in my system and i want to **import** that into openproject and map the contents of file to **openproject database**.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: llya, i want to import a .csv file into the openproject database. In short, i want to create a import plugin

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Ilya this is my requirement I am looking for ways of how we can do it

Answer (score 0):

in the past when I have to load a CSV file into the DB I like todo a rake task.

My task looks like:

```
#/lib/tasks/import_csv.rake
require 'csv'
namespace :imports do
desc 'import from csv'
  task :variants => :environment do
    Dir['lib/csv/files/*'].each do |file|
      csv_text = File.read(file)
      csv_text = csv_text.encode("UTF-16be", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?").encode('UTF-8')
      csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
      csv.each_with_index do |row, index|
        something = Something.find_or_initialize_by(name: row['name'])
        something.address                   = row['address']
        something.save
      end
      file_processed = file.gsub('/files/', '/files_processed/')
      File.rename(file, file_processed) unless Rails.env  == 'development'
    end
  end
end
```

I hope that this helps :)

Comment: In which place should the .csv should be present?